# How to read the text below the mouse when clicking on a tkinter Text widget and paste it in an Entry widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, mouseevent, tkinter-entry, tkinter-text

I am writing a program that pulls data from a server. Initially, the program asks the server to print the data available for a specific day. The output on the Text widget is shown in the for loop:

```
def set_id(event):
    entry1.delete(0, 'end')
    entry1.insert(0, "The text I have just clicked")

tex1.tag_config('clickable', foreground="blue", underline=True)
tex1.tag_bind('clickable', "<Button-1>", set_id)

for n in range(0, n_samples, 1):
    tex1.insert("end", str(json[n]['_id']) + "\n", 'clickable')
    # you get for example: 123\n121\n111 ecc
```

Later I want the user to be able to click on any of the printed samples id and paste that value to another Entry widget. Can it be done?

I hope I was able to explain myself, if not please ask for clarification.
Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```py
tex1.get('insert linestart', 'insert lineend')
```

to get the ID where the input cursor is.  However since you bind on `<Button-1>`, the input cursor is not updated when the callback is executed.  You need to bind on `<ButtonRelease-1>` instead:

```py
def set_id(event):
    entry1.delete(0, 'end')
    entry1.insert(0, tex1.get('insert linestart', 'insert lineend'))
...
tex1.tag_bind('clickable', "<ButtonRelease-1>", set_id) # bind on <ButtonRelease-1> instead
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Are there other commands like 'insert linestart' and 'insert lineend' in order to get only the text between two spaces or the first N characters? EDIT: Well I have realized that I can use use the classic String functions at that point! Thanks again

Comment: @AndreaPython You can reference [here](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html#modifying).